# How do I render Component into _slug.vue to get the content?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to get the content of a markdown page. If I render it in _slug.vue without the component it works fine, but I don't want to duplicate the code, so I need to pass 'about' from slug to component.

This is the component Content.vue:

```html
<template>
<div>
    <nuxt-content :document="article" />
</div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
      props:{
          message:{
              type: String,
              required: true,
              default: "hello"
          }
      },
    async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
      const article = await $content('blog', params.slug).fetch()
      return { article }
    }
  }
</script>
<style>
.wrapper {
  @apply min-h-screen flex justify-center items-center text-center mx-auto;
}
.card {
  @apply p-10 rounded-lg text-emerald-500 bg-emerald-100 shadow-lg;
  .title {
    @apply text-6xl font-bold;
  }
}
</style>
```

This is the _slug.vue

```html
<template>
<div>
    <NavBar />
    <Carousel />
    <!-- <nuxt-content :document="article" /> -->
    <Content message='blog'/>
</div>
</template>


<script>
/*
  export default {
    async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
      const article = await $content('blog', params.slug).fetch()
      return { article }
    }
  }
  */
</script>
```

I get this error:

```
Property or method "article" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `asyncData` in non-page components. Try using `fetch`

Comment: @Teej Thanks, will look into that but I think fetch is only for http? Not for requesting a local markdown page... not too sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the duplication I believe this is an option you can do:

You would retrieve the data from the page component and just pass the article as props to the content.

```
/* _slug.vue */
<template>
<div>
    <NavBar />
    <Carousel />
    <Content :article='article'/>
</div>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
      const article = await $content('blog', params.slug).fetch()
      return { article }
    }
  }
</script>
```

```
/* Content */
<template>
<div>
    <nuxt-content :document="article" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    article: Object,
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks yea that works. I guess the trick was to leave asynData in the _slug.vue huh? I see how this could be beneficial if I had a bunch of styling to do in the Content component, or even render the a Toc.vue component  and style it then place it inside Content.vue component. That would help me reuse the code.

Comment: Just for the record for anyone reading this, asyncdata is only for pages as stated [here in the docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#async-data).